# Drupal 6: How to set up & use Mercurial for my Drupal projects

Tags: svn, drupal, mercurial, drupal-6, bluehost

I need to start using version control system for my Drupal projects, and I decided on Mercurial.

During last 2 days I have been googling to find some tutorials, guides, tips, anything about "how to use mercurial for my drupal projects", but I just can't find anything! :/

Can you advise any link or tutorial or anything for how to set up & use mercurial for my own Drupal projects?

I can go for any other solution as well such as GIT, SubVersion, etc. if they will make things easier for drupal.

What do you guys use for your drupal projects?!

Appreciate helps!! thanks a lot!

---

**[edit 1]**

*as you know Drupal has so much to do with database, so it should be a good solution for that as well. For example editing any View Block (View module), etc...*

---

**[edit 2]**

I'm on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use GIT instead of hg, for the simple reason that Drupal itself is in the process of moving it's CVS repository to GIT.

If you are using Mac OS X, I would suggest [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) which is a nice GUI that will allow you to do most common things you want to do.

About views, I would suggest that you use modules such as [features](http://drupal.org/project/features), it will convert your views to code, so you can check them in. It also allows you to do a lot of other nice things, like reverting views back to the default defined in the code.

Git with Drupal is not much different than Git with X, git is a VCS, so it's all about storing and sharing code changes. When I started programming and started using Git, I found that [this guide](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/) helped me understand how to use git and what to use it for.

Comment: yeah I know about that. can you link any "git with drupal for real dummies" tutorial, video, anything? I just can't find :/